# EPPlus C# でAddShape()した図形をグループ化したい

Tags: c#, epplus

EPPlus本家のサイトをみてもGroupメソッドの使い方がよくわからなかったためこちらで質問させていただきます。
以下のようにws(WorkSheet)に図形をAddするだけでシート上に図形を置くことができますが、置いた図形をグループ化したいです。

```
 ExcelShape shape = ws.Drawings.AddShape($"AAA", eShapeStyle.Rect);
```

EPPlusのWorkSheetオブジェクトにはGroup()というメソッドがあるのですが、使い方がよくわかりません。
どなたかご教授お願いします。

Comment: この質問含めて、回答がついても放置している質問が大量にありますが、回答内容で解決したのであれば回答の承認をするか、それ以外の方法で自己解決したのであれば、解決した方法を自分で回答してください。回答内容で解決できなかったのであれば、その結果をコメントに書いた方がよいと思います。正しい回答ではなかったかどうか後から見た人が判断できますし、解決しなかった場合でも、別の提案が出来る場合もあるかもしれないので。

Answer (score 0):

ExcelShapeの方にGroupメソッドがあり、引数は ExcelDrawing[] なので、
多分グループ化したいShapeを配列にして渡せばいいんじゃないですかね。（試してません）
[ExcelDrawing.Group(ExcelDrawing[])](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/6.1/api/OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawing.html#OfficeOpenXml_Drawing_ExcelDrawing_Group_OfficeOpenXml_Drawing_ExcelDrawing___)